# is it necessary to have foreign key for simple tables

Tags: sql, database-normalization

have a table called `RoundTable`

It has the following columns

```
RoundName
RoundDescription
RoundType
RoundLogo
```

Now the `RoundType` will be having values like "`Team`", "`Individual`", "`Quiz`"

is it necessary to have a one more table called "`RoundTypes`" with columns

```
TypeID
RoundType
```

and remove the `RoundType` from the rounds table and have a column "`TypeID`" which has a foreign key to this `RoundType` table?

Some say that if you have the RoundType in same table it is like hard-coding as there will be lot of round types in future.
is it like if there are going to be only 2-3 round types, i need not have foreign key??

Comment: **YES!** - that's the **whole point** of having referential integrity in databases - to make sure only **valid data** is stored.

Comment: It is better programming to have all type in table and have the id on the other. You can do it as you want but what is you want to get all types? You will have select from table distinct typename. Not a good practice

Answer (score 4):

Is it necessary?  Obviously not.  SQL works fine either way.  In a properly defined database, you would do one of two things for `RoundType`:

1. Have a lookup table
2. Have a constraint that checks that values are within an agreed upon set (and I would put `enum`s into this category)

If you have a lookup table, I would advocate having an auto-incremented id (called `RoundTypeId`) for it.  Remember, that in a larger database, such a table would often have more than two columns:

- CreatedAt -- when it was created
- CreatedBy -- who created it
- CreatedOn -- where it was created (important for distributed systems)
- Long name

In a more advanced system, you might also need to internationalize the system -- that is, make it work for multiple languages.  Then you would be looking up the actual string value in other tables.

Comment: so is it ok if I have entities defined in C#, say a static class "RoundType" and have all allowed values defined in that to check before inserting?

Comment: @vignesh . . . I am a strong advocate of using *database* constructs to validate data in the database.  This puts the code for the database in one place.

Answer (score 2):

> is it like if there are going to be only 2-3 round types, i need not
>   have foreign key??

Usually it's just the opposite: If you have a different value for most of the records (like in a "lastName" column) you won't use a lookup table.

If, however, you know that you will have a limited set of allowed/possible values, a lookup table referenced via a foreign key is probably the better solution.

Maybe read up on "database normalization", starting perhaps @ [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

Answer (score 1):

Actually you need to have separate table if you have following association between entities,

1. One to many
2. Many to many

because of virtue of these association simple DBMS becomes **R**DBMS ( Relation .)

Now ask simple question,
Whether my single record in round table have multiple roundTypes?
If so.. Make a new table and have foreign key in ROUNDTable.

Otherwise no.

Answer (score 0):

yeah I think you should normalize it. Because if you will not do so then definitely you have to enter the round types (value) again and again for each record which is not good practice at all in case if you have large data. so i will suggest you to make another table

however later on you can make a view  to get the desired result as fallow

create view vw_anyname
as 
select RoundName, RoundDescription , RoundLogo, RoundType from roundtable join tblroundtype 
on roundtable.TypeID = tblroundtype .typeid

select * from vw_anyname